# parfor does not print to screen simultaneously from two functions?

Tags: matlab, parfor

i'm trying to test a very simple parfor function which calls two other functions that each prints to screen a number: 1 and 2, so i'm expecting it will print something like this in random order to the console:
1
2
2
1
2
1
1
2

but it will always finish one function before another and give me ordered outputs:
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2

so to me the parfor doesn't seem to be parallel...
here is my code

```
function mainfunction(hObject, eventdata, handles)
matlabpool ('open',2); 
x=1;
y=2;
parfor i=1:2
    if(i==1)
        function1(x);
    else
        function2(y);
    end
end
matlabpool close;


function function1(x)
for i=1:100
    x
end

function function2(y)
for i=1:100
    y
end
```

does anyone have an idea why this is not working? thanks

Comment: Your `function1` and `function2` execute too quickly to see that. Try adding `pause`'s in the functions and you will see the behaviour you think you should see.

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The technical reason is that you're not manually flushing your output to the command window. `pause` gives the system time to do this, but it can be a bit of hack unless you don't care what the delay is. A possibly faster scheme for general use is to call [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) instead (`pause` calls this implicitly). [This page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/using-drawnow-efficiently.html) nicely summarizes the usage of this function. [Some even suggest](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/solving-a-matlab-hang-problem) using both `drawnow` and `pause` in certain situations. More interesting [commentary here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7309-is-pause-a-superset-of-drawnow) too.